# Loading and processing multiple images

Tags: image, image-processing, opencv

```
    #include "iostream"
    #include "cv.h"
    #include "highgui.h"
    #include "cvaux.h"
    #include "cxmisc.h"
    #include "math.h"

    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;

    int main(){

    int height, width, x, y, i, minX, minY, maxX, maxY;
    char imgFileName[100];


    IplImage *origImage = cvLoadImage("data set baybayin/0000.jpg", -1);
    height = origImage->height;
    width = origImage->width;

    IplImage *grayImage = cvCreateImage(cvSize(width, height), 8, 1);
    IplImage *binImage = cvCreateImage(cvSize(width, height), 8, 1);


    //Pre-processing phase
    //image cleaning
    cvCvtColor(origImage, grayImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cvDilate(grayImage, grayImage, NULL, 1);
    cvSmooth(grayImage, grayImage, CV_GAUSSIAN, 21, 21, 0, 0);
    //image binarization
    cvThreshold(grayImage, binImage, 120, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    //cvNormalize(binImage,binImage,0,1,CV_MINMAX);

    //getting image info
    minX = width;
    minY = height;
    maxX = 0;
    maxY = 0;

    //image cropping
    CvScalar s;

    //finding the boundaries
    for (x=0; x<width-1; x++){
        for(y=0; y<height-1; y++){
            //getting pixel values
            s = cvGet2D(binImage, y, x);
            //printf("%f\n", s.val[0]);
            //identifying boundaries
            if (s.val[0] == 0){
                //printf("HELLO");
                minX = min(minX, x);
                minY = min(minY, y);
                maxX = max(maxX, x);
                maxY = max(maxY, y);
                //printf("%d\n", minY);
            }   
        }
    }

    //creating rectangle
    CvRect rect = cvRect(minX, minY, maxX-minX, maxY-minY);
    //sets the part of the image to be cropped
    cvSetImageROI(binImage, rect);
    IplImage *cropImage = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(binImage), 8, 1);
    IplImage *newImage = cvCreateImage(cvSize(400, 400), 8, 1);

    //copies cropped image to new declared image
    cvCopy(binImage, cropImage, NULL);
    //cvSaveImage("bin/binImage16.jpg", binImage);

    cvSaveImage("data set baybayin/cropImage0.jpg", cropImage);


    cvResetImageROI(binImage);
    cvReleaseImage(&origImage);
    cvReleaseImage(&binImage);
    cvReleaseImage(&grayImage);
    cvReleaseImage(&cropImage);
    cvReleaseImage(&newImage);


    }
```

Hi may I just ask about how can I load multiple images in my code above? Because this code only loads and processes one image and I can barely understand some of the instructions online. I'm sorry I'm a newbie. I would also want to ask about the code after processing; how can I save the new and processed images into another folder with the corresponding filenames? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You handle multiple images by declaring additional IplImage objects, and either loading them from file:

```
IplImage *anotherImage = cvLoadImage("data set baybayin/0000.jpg", -1);
```

or creating them yourself:

```
IplImage *grayImage = cvCreateImage(cvSize(width, height), 8, 1);
```

If you need to do the same thing to multiple images, then the wise thing to do is to write a function that accepts an `IplImage *` as input and returns a newly created `IplImage *` as output.  Note that this newly created image will have to be freed with `cvRelease` by the calling function.

Alternatively, if you're processing the images independently of each other, then code your executable to process a single image, and loop over images in your command-line shell (bash or equivalent).

You save images using the `cvSaveImage` function.  Handling the pathname manipulations is outside the scope of the library -- it's your responsibility to provide the path of the output image.  In C, you can do this using character array manipulations.  In C++, you have libraries like [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm) to help you along.  If you go with the alternative I mentioned above, then you can use your shell's path manipulation functionality (e.g. [bash](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/bash-string-manipulation/)).

If you're a complete newbie with OpenCV, then I'd recommend [this book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596516130.do): while it only handles the old C interface (not the new C++ one), it will improve your understanding of the library.

Comment: I don't get your instructions easily, sorry. How about having strings to be read in a particular file?

Comment: I've read about saving all the filenames in a text doc and reading all of them so that the program could find the needed images. Like a text document containing these: 00000.jpg 00001.jpg 00002.jpg and the like. After reading this text doc, the images will then be loaded. However, I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: If you're unable to implement a program that reads filenames from a text file, then you probably need to review your general C++ knowledge (completely unrelated to OpenCV).  For example: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/.  Once you have that under control, then try working with OpenCV.  Good luck.